# Problems with perl regex when matching a variable

Tags: regex, string, perl

I have to match a string in format Krait400.1C.28, when I store it in a variable:

```
$string_to_match = "Krait400.1C.28"

foreach (@line)
{
  if($_ =~ /$string_to_match/i)
  {
    print "found";
  }
  else
  {
    print "notfound";
  }
 }
```

it doesn't match. But if I replace `$string_to_match` with `"Krait400.28.1C"` it matches. Also, there are other strings which do match and in the same format like *xxxx.yy*.1C, but I have problems with some of them like `"Krait400.28.1C"`, it is acting really weird

I have counted characters, everything is same, but I don't know why it is not matching!

Please help me out!

Comment: You need to give us a sample of a line of text that should match but doesn't. Also, you should use `/\Q$string_to_match/i` to escape any metacharacters. In this case the dots in the pattern will match any single character in the object text, instead of matching dots. But this isn't the source of your problem, as it would make it match lines when it shouldn't and your problem is the reverse of that

Comment: Maybe you have quotation marks in file and it look like: `"Krait400.1C.28"`? When you replace `/$string_to_match/i` you put there only string or string with `"`?

Comment: @user: Removing the quotes from the pattern won't stop it from matching

Comment: There's a missing `;` after the assignment. After adding the string to the `@line` array, I got "found" back.

Comment: @Borodin I meant the difference between `/Krait400.1C.28/i` and `/"Krait400.1C.28"/i`

Comment: It works for me: http://ideone.com/5SR4eY

Comment: @user When you substitute a variable into a regexp, it doesn't include the quotes.

Comment: @Barmar I know, but maybe Jiniac create something like `/"Krait400.1C.28"/i` when he replace var and it work's because he have text with quotes in file.

Comment: @user: But do you understand that a pattern *without* the quotes would work fine as well?

Comment: @user The regex `/foo/` matches the text `foo` *as well as* the text `"foo"`.

Comment: @Barmar Yes, I understand.

Comment: @user I don't get what you're saying. He shows in the question what he created. If he wrote `$string_to_match = '"Krait400.1C.28"';` then it would be a problem.

Comment: Or if he wrote `=~ /"$string_to_match"/`

Comment: @Barmar and what I'm saying is that maybe Jiniac did something like `=~ /"$string_to_match"/`

Comment: @user Or maybe they did something like `=~ /foo$string_to_match/`. We can speculate all day about what the OP's code really is and why they (apparently) mis-copied it when composing this question, but that seems rather pointless.

Comment: Actually it is simply Krait... not with the quotes! I am very sorry for the confusion created. Also, @Borodin I tried \Q, but that also doesnt work! Something really crazy is going on!

Comment: @Jiniac If you really want help, show what you're actually doing, including the value of `@line`.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry guys, the bug wasnt in the regex, it was in a subroutine I called after the first element mismatches, and then it used to mismatch the rest. It was really hard to figure that part, as it was going into the loop where I perform regex and it wasnt matching there!

Sorry for all your troubles!

Thanks a lot though for your inputs!